# What is "GPUwatch Interceptor app"

Tags: malware

I was going through my settings today and I clicked on privacy then checked my special access and noticed something I've never seen before. An app called watch GPU interceptor it had full access permissions with no description. I turned it off went back to the main menu a few minutes later I went back to special access and it was still there and set to on, full access. I searched everywhere I could on my phone went through apps permissions I couldn't find it as an app. I found GPU watch which was in developer options, I turned off developer options then went back to special access and had to turn off ""GPU watch Interceptor "" again. I cannot find that exact phrase in Google search. I'd like to know if this was something that I turned on in developer options or if it was some sort of Hack / malware.
I'm using a Samsung S10 Plus, with Android 10 on Verizon and home Wi-Fi
I have added a screen capture of what I saw

Thank you[image]

Answer (score 1):

### No, It doesn't a malware.

***GPUWatch*** aids developers in their monitoring and measurement of performance between Vulkan and OpenGL ES. It’s now packed with new features, such as overlaid measurement results and real-time information on-screen – all made possible without separate installation or PC connection. [Samsung NewsRoom](https://news.samsung.com/global/motion-graphic-sdc18-samsung-expands-developer-support-to-deliver-premium-mobile-gaming)

How is showed in the smartphone screen :
[image]

*image retired from link GDC19*

For to deepen in GPUWatch I recommend to you two Youtube videos: 
[GDC19](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FFxcBZ7Isdw):  A talk of HyoKeun Lee addressing about why use that tool.
[GDC18](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9ZdW57ut6MA):  HyoKeun again, showing how to use GPUWatch.